# Passing BeginInvoke as a parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, methods

Suppose I want to have a method that passes the [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) method of an object as a parameter.  How would I do that?  The call looks like this:

```
MyRandomMethod(SomeControl.BeginInvoke);
```

What would the method definition for MyRandomMethod be?

Part of the problem is that BeginInvoke has overloads, so the compiler gets confused as to which one I am try to pass as a parameter.  Maybe I need to find a way to say which version of BeginInvoke I am referring to?  (Though I would imagine that would be decided by the parameter type)

Comment: It's a code smell but I can't see the code.  A lambda fixes your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyRandomMethod` would have to have a parameter with a delegate which matches one of the overloads for `SomeControl.BeginInvoke`. For example:

```
public void MyRandomMethod(Func<Delegate, IAsyncResult> foo)
```

or

```
public void MyRandomMethod(Func<Delegate, object[], IAsyncResult> foo)
```

(But please don't overload `MyRandomMethod` itself with both of these signatures, as otherwise you're just asking for confusion.)